# access Iframe element in asp.net webpage

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe

I am using asp.net 4.5.1 webform. I have a asp.net page "Default.aspx".I have a IFrame in this page :

```
<iframe id="myFrame" name="myFrame" src="" runat="server"></iframe>
```

also I have a button on this page. On the click event of the button I set src of Iframe which is not in my domain. forexample : src="www.google.com". when Iframe become loaded inside of that is a textarea.

```
<textarea class="textarea" name="msg" id="msg" ></textarea>
```

I want after each time that my Iframe loaded (all the time that I click on my button in default.aspx which force the Iframe load), change the text of msg textarea. I used jquery but I wasnt successful. is there any way to do?

Comment: What msg you want to give in textarea?

Comment: I wanna set "Hello" or any other text as Value of textarea

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ejyk/1/)

```
$("#btn1").on("click", function () {
    $("#msg").text("Hello");
});
```

Comment: This code work correct but not in my case, which the textarea is inside of Iframe and also Iframe's src is external link

Comment: Is Your `textarea` from external site?